why is $\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_j\partial(\sigma_j)=\sum_{i}(-1)^i \sigma|[v_0,...,\hat{v_i},....,v_n]$
There is some confusion regarding the boundary map
According to Gereon Quick book (see page no:$44$) boundary operator is define by

$$\partial_n:S_n(X)\to S_{n-1}(X)$$,
$$\partial(\sum_{j=1}^m a_j\sigma_j)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_j\partial(\sigma_j)$$

According to Allen Hatcher book as shown on
page no $108$

A  boundary map $\partial_n:C_n(X) \to C_{n-1}(X)$ is defined  by the  same formula as before


$\partial_n(\sigma)=\sum_{i}(-1)^i \sigma|[v_0,...,\hat{v_i},....,v_n]$

My thinking: Here $S_n(X)=C_n(X)=\{\text{n- chains in}  X\}$ and  $|[v_0,...,\hat{v_i},....,v_n]$  is  face inclusion
However, I am confused about this
$$\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_j\partial(\sigma_j)=\sum_{i}(-1)^i \sigma|[v_0,...,\hat{v_i},....,v_n]$$
In my opinion, Allen Hatcher's and Gereon Quick's definitions of boundary operators are different
My question: why is $$\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_j\partial(\sigma_j)=\sum_{i}(-1)^i \sigma|[v_0,...,\hat{v_i},....,v_n]$$

There must be a misunderstanding. In the first definition from Quick the boundary map is not actually defined completely. All that has been done (at least in the definition you gave above) is take an arbitrary element of $S_n(X)$ which is some linear combination of some $n$-simplices $\sum_{i=0}^m a_j \sigma_j$ and then "use" the fact that $\partial_n$ is a group homomorphism. But the definition lacks how $\partial_n$ is defined on $n$-simplices $\sigma_j$. Exactly this part of the definition is given in the second definition. There, the $\sigma$ is just an $n$-simplex (not an $n$-chain) and the boundary operator is defined. That means that boundary operator is defined on the basis of $C_n(X)$.
So all in all, for a full definition of the boundary map you have to put the two definitions together. You first define for $\sigma \in X_n$ an $n$-simplex:
$$\partial_n(\sigma):=\sum_i (-1)^{i}\sigma \mid [v_0,...,\widehat{v_i},...,v_n]$$
and extend this to all of $C_n(X)$ by linearity as in the first definition, i.e.
$$\partial_n : C_n(X) \to C_{n-1}(X), \sum_{j=0}^m a_j \sigma_j \mapsto \sum_{j=0}^m a_j \partial_n(\sigma_j)$$

okay  thanks  you .I thought  that $\sigma$ is an $n$ chain
